# Proper placement of q.all inside array.map with _.forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have the following code which searches my mongodb using `find()` using values extracted using `array.map`. Said search returns an object, which I then used a `_.forEach` to extract the values.

I used [this article](https://daveceddia.com/waiting-for-promises-in-a-loop/) as basis, however the difference between his examples and mine was he used only one loop. I'm using two. In this case, where should I put my `q.all()`?

Here's my code. **Please note that is server-side:**

```
'use strict';
var q = require('q');

exports.downloadEmployee = function (req, res) {
    var tempCtr = [];

    if (req.params.hasdr === "yes") {
        return queries.generateDirectReportsCSV(req.params.id).then(function (directReports) {
            return directReports;
        }).then(function (directReports) {
            var empIDcoll = _.pluck(directReports.Data, "employeenumber");
            return empIDcoll;
        }).then(function (empIDcoll) {
            var promises = [];

            empIDcoll.map(function (id) {

                return EmployeeInfo.find({ employeeID: id }, function (err, results) {
                    if (err) { return err; }

                    _.forEach(results, function (item) {
                        if (item) {
                            tempCtr.push({
                                employeeID: item.employeeID,
                                employeeName: item.employeeName
                            });
                            promises.push(tempCtr);
                        }
                    });
                });

                q.all(promises).then(function (results) {
                    return res.json(results);
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

When I run this, I don't get any result back.

Any answers will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

**UPDATE:** I've decided to revise my code and replaced `array.map` with the usual `for loop`:

```
.then(function (empIDcoll) {

    for (var i = 0; i <= empIDcoll.length - 1; i++) {
        var promise = EmployeeInfo.find({ employeeID: empIDcoll[i] }, function (err, results) {
            if (err) { return err; }

            _.forEach(results, function (item) {
                if (item) {
                    tempCtr.push({
                        employeeID: item.employeeID,
                        employeeName: item.employeeName,
                        currentShift: item.currentShift,
                        isOpenToIntlAssignment: item.isOpenToIntlAssignment,
                        desiredRole1: item.desiredRole1,
                        desiredRole2: item.desiredRole2,
                        desiredRole3: item.desiredRole3,
                        desiredRoleOther: item.desiredRoleOther,
                        passportInfo: item.passportInfo,
                        visaInfo: item.visaInfo,
                        yrsInIT: item.yrsInIT,
                        yrsAsCustomerPM: item.yrsAsCustomerPM,
                        yrsAsCustomerProgM: item.yrsAsCustomerProgM,
                        primaryDomain: item.primaryDomain,
                        primaryDomainOther: item.primaryDomainOther,
                        primaryIndustry: item.primaryIndustry,
                        primaryIndustryOther: item.primaryIndustryOther,
                        isPMPCertified: item.isPMPCertified,
                        pmpCertExpiryDate: item.pmpCertExpiryDate,
                        isPGMPCertified: item.isPGMPCertified,
                        pgmpCertExpiryDate: item.pgmpCertExpiryDate,
                        isScrumCertified: item.isScrumCertified,
                        scrumCertExpiryDate: item.scrumCertExpiryDate,
                        biggestProjectTCV: item.biggestProjectTCV,
                        biggestTeamSizeManaged: item.biggestTeamSizeManaged,
                        avgTeamSizeManaged: item.avgTeamSizeManaged,
                        biggestBilledFTE: item.biggestBilledFTE,
                        avgBilledFTE: item.avgBilledFTE
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        promises.push(promise);
    }

    return q.all(promises).then(function(data){
        return res.json(data);
    });

});
```

...but it's still not returning anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was almost correct the first time!

When you did:

```
var promises = [];
empIDcoll.map(function (id) {
    return EmployeeInfo.find({ employeeID: id }, function (err, results) {
        if (err) { return err; }
        _.forEach(results, function (item) {
            if (item) {
                tempCtr.push({
                    employeeID: item.employeeID,
                    employeeName: item.employeeName
                });
                promises.push(tempCtr);
            }
        });
    });

    q.all(promises).then(function (results) {
        return res.json(results);
    });
});
```

You had the `q.all` location wrong (inside the `.map`); and you pushed *objects* inside your `promises` array, instead of actual *promises*. Try to do something like:

```
// Here, we will build an array of promises by transforming each element of `empIDcoll` to a promise (via `.map`).
var promises = empIDcoll.map(function (id) {
    return EmployeeInfo.find({ employeeID: id }).exec(); // I assume that .exec() will return a promise.
});

q.all(promises).then(function (results) { // `results` will be an array, each element will contain the result of each promise pushed to `promises`.
    return res.json(results);
});
```

Try this. This may need some tweaking maybe (let us know), for I don't really know the structure of your application / models.

Comment: It works! I just transferred my `_.forEach` inside the `q.all()`, made a few adjustments inside it and finally it works! Your solution was simple and clear. Thank you @SinDeus! :D

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `return` statement before `EmployeeInfo.find`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Unfortunately it didn't work. :( It threw an empty response back to my client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Just look,

```
var promises = questions.map(function(question) {

        return $http({
            url   : 'upload/question',
            method: 'POST',
            data  : question
        });

    });

    return $q.all(promises);
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is done in the client-side. As much as possible, I want to execute `q.all()` in the server-side. Anyways, I tried this and the response is taking too long to come back...

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to stop looping through the employeeId in the first place.
you can use mongoDB's [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator like this

```
EmployeeInfo.find({ employeeID: {$in: empIDcoll} }, function (err, results) {
     if(err) {
       //handle error
       return err;
     }

     res.json(results);
});
```

But as I dont know about your application I really can't judge maybe you want to loop through empIdColl.

---

**Looping through the empIdColl**

Now I'm not sure that your monogdb query will return promise or not so to be on safer side I'll assume that it doesn't

```
var promises = empIDcoll.map(function (id) {
    var singleDefer = q.defer(); //create a deferred object which has promise in it

    EmployeeInfo.find({ employeeID: id }, function(err, results) {
         if(err) {
             return singleDefer.reject(err);
         }

         return singleDefer.resolve(results); //resolve whole array
    });

    return singleDefer.promise;
});

q.all(promises)
.then(function (arrayOfResults) {
    var responseData = [];

    arrayOfResuls.forEach(function(results) {
          results.forEach(function(individualResult) {
              if(individualResult) {
                   responseData.push({
                       employeeID: item.employeeID,
                       ...
                       ...
                       avgBilledFTE: item.avgBilledFTE
                   });
              }
          });
    });

    return res.json(responseData);
})
.catch(function(err) {
    //handle error
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting my working solution here for the benefit of those who might encounter the same problem in the future. Thank you to SinDeus for the simple and concise solution. :)

```
.then(function (empIDcoll) {

        // push user's employee number in first row
        empIDcoll.unshift(req.params.id);

        // return resolved promises from EmployeeInfo.find()
        // this will return user's direct reports' information (if any)
        var promises = empIDcoll.map(function (id) {
            return EmployeeInfo.find({ employeeID: id }).exec();
        });

        // Take resolved promises from above statement and iterate to get final results.
        q.all(promises).then(function (results) {
            _.forEach(results, function (item) {
                var len = item.length - 1;
                if (len >= 0) {
                    tempCtr.push({
                        employeeID: item[0].employeeID,
                        employeeName: item[0].employeeName
                        // ... other fields here ...
                    });
                }
            });
            return res.json(tempCtr);
        });
    });
}
```